# Why doesn't K remember that J was in the past with him?

Tags: men-in-black, men-in-black-3

I saw the questions about "[Why can J remember everything about K?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17377/4056)" and stuff, but there's something I don't get.

J actually changed the past going to 1969 and helping K with the ArcNet.

Ok, so logically, K must remember J coming from future and helping him, because that was what really happened now. That is now the true story about July 16th 1969. J, as a time traveller, came from future and helped his friend K.

So, while all this is logical, why the hell can't Agent K remember J as a time traveller who came from future?

Comment: I'm not sure what context you're asking about, regarding the K that doesn't seem to remember J.  Are you talking about K from MiB 1, or K from MiB 2 after the memory wipe, or one of the Ks in MiB 3?

Comment: sorry for not specify this... but i was talking about MiB3

Comment: @Iszi has a point: K was memory wiped; in MIB2 we find out that he was wiped more than once, the first time of which before the events in MIB1.

Answer (score 16):

K does remember J. It's even implied that K kept a watchful eye over J as he grew up after his father died. But like a good agent he knows better than to play around with causality, so he never lets J find out about their link.

Comment: Friends don't let friends screw around with Time.

Answer (score 14):

From watching MiB 3, I was under the impression that K in the future *did* remember J.  He just didn't let on because it may change the future until J also knew about it.

Comment: Yeah... so then... when K recruited J in MiB 1, you suppose he already knew who J is?

Yeah... actually your awnser is the most convincent. Thanks!

(sorry for my bad english)